# How to replace Rails site with Wordpress site from another server / domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku

I'm trying to figure out how to move a Rails app from www.domain1.com to a subdirectory (ie. www.domain1.com/subdirectory), and then transfer a Wordpress site I've been developing from www.domain2.com to www.domain1.com.

Basically, I want to keep my old Rails site and make it accessible via a subdirectory, and replace it with a new Wordpress site that I've been developing on another domain name / host.

I did not create the Rails site and know little about Rails, so I'm not sure where to even begin.  The Rails site is hosted on Heroku.. can that also host the Wordpress site that's currently on another host?

Sorry if these seems incoherent or make little sense.. I kind of just need a suggestion of where to begin.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're not going to be able to host both php and ruby code on the same app in heroku.  It sounds like the rails site is no longer going to be used in production and is only there for backup purposes.  In that case, you'll be fine running that app on heroku's free tier.

So what you should do it this.

- Keep your rails/heroku app exactly where it is.
- Create a subdomain with your dns provider to point to the old rails site (something like oldsite.mydomain.com).
- Point the new domain to heroku.
- Downgrade your heroku account to the free plan.

Then you should go ahead and setup your wordpress site wherever.  I've never used heroku for a wordpress app.  For all of my professional sites I use wpengine.  I wouldn't even consider going anywhere else because my experience there has been so great!  Change your primary domain to point to that wordpress site.

Done!